# ERROR: missing FROM-clause entry for table "raw_data" in postgres stored procedure

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures

When calling a stored procedure that contains the following loop in it, get an error

> ERROR: missing FROM-clause entry for table "raw_data" SQL state: 42P01

Note that raw_data is not a table.

Stored procedure loop block :

```
FOR row_data IN SELECT * from temp_alerts_for_today_table

    LOOP

    PERFORM * FROM temp_mails_for_today_table AS temp 
    WHERE temp.mailrecipient = row_data.mailrecipient 
    AND temp.alertconfigurationid = row_data.alertconfigurationid;

    IF(NOT FOUND) THEN

    INSERT INTO temp_mails_for_today_table(mailrecipient, alertconfigurationid, mailsubject, mailcontent, instrumentlist)
    VALUES(row_data.mailrecipient,row_data.alertconfigurationid,row_data.mailsubject,row_data.mailcontent,row_data.instrument);

    ELSE

    SELECT temp.instrumentlist INTO instrument_list 
    FROM temp_mails_for_today_table AS temp 
    WHERE temp.mailrecipient = row_data.mailrecipient 
    AND temp.alertconfigurationid = row_data.alertconfigurationid;

    IF (instrument_list IS NULL) THEN

    UPDATE temp_mails_for_today_table 
    SET instrumentlist = raw_data.instrument 
    WHERE mailrecipient = row_data.mailrecipient 
    AND alertconfigurationid = row_data.alertconfigurationid;

    ELSE

    instrument_list := instrument_list || ',' ||  raw_data.instrument;

    UPDATE temp_mails_for_today_table 
    SET instrumentlist = instrument_list 
    WHERE mailrecipient = row_data.mailrecipient 
    AND alertconfigurationid = row_data.alertconfigurationid;

    END IF;

    END IF;

    END LOOP;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `raw_data.instrument` with `row_data.instrument`